# Upgrade Status failed but June 2016 CU Build number listed

Tags: 2013, upgrade

I've upgraded our sharepoint farm to the latest June 2016 CU and there were errors. The upgrade status shows 5 Errors. Errors with missing features that we fixed by uninstalling them (4 error messages for differend DB's with the same feature in english and german, 1 message that the upgrade failed because of the mentioned feature error)

Now we ran the configuration wizard again and the build number 15.0.4833.1000 shows as installed in product and patch installation status.

The database status shows "no action required" for all databases.

How do I get rid of the Failed Status and is the upgrade now succesful or not?

Answer (score 0):

Is this in the area where it lists the logs for the previous upgrades/database upgrades?

If so, it'll never clear.  It's just the status of that specific upgrade attempt.  It'll never change.

Is there a subsequent "Success" when you reran the config wizard?

Edit (not enough points):  I don't think a run of the config wizard will show unless it actually performs an upgrade operation.  If you can run the wizard and it completes successfully, I'd ignore the previous failures, knowing that you've cleaned up what you can.

Comment: Yes, that is the area. And no there is no subsequent Success. I ran the wizard again, but nothing appears